# i keep getting "Unresolved dependencies", (in the image below) in a Jupyter notebook (java)

Tags: java, variables, methods, jupyter-notebook

[image]

My project requires me to separate a program into multiple methods and call each method and test it, individually. Then have a separate method in which all the previous methods have been called to run the program. I can put the whole thing in one method but that is against the rules.

I have defined total_money and total_visitors in method 1 (the user inputs the value), and I want to use those values in my next method but when I define them again, I get Unresolved dependencies error.

I am using Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Take the [tour] and restructure your question posting code and errors as text rather than images.  Try to create a minimal, reproducible example for others to utilize.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strongly typed language hence you always must declare the variable's type.
Also, in order to pass parameters to a function, you must specify them in the function's signature.
  `public static void method2(int visitors, double money){`